# How to use BibLaTeX's shortauthor field in pandoc-citeproc?

Tags: latex, pandoc, biblatex, pandoc-citeproc

In BibLaTeX it is possible to specify an abbreviation for an author, so that the short term is used in citations and the long term in the bibliography:

```
@misc{nasa,
    author = {{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}},
    shortauthor = {{NASA}},
    title = {Rocket Science},
    year = 2019
}
```

Then the text becomes:

> Rocket science is difficult (NASA 2019).

And the bibliography:

> National Aeronautics and Space Administration (NASA), 2019, "Rocket Science".

Is this behaviour possible using pandoc-citeproc?

In case this is relevant, my Pandoc command is `pandoc chapters/*.md --standalone --filter pandoc-fignos --filter pandoc-citeproc --template template.tex --top-level-division=part --listings --output out.pdf` and the References section looks like this:

```
---
bibliography: references.bib
link-citations: true
nocite: '@*'
---
## References {.unnumbered}
```

In the Pandoc manual, [I came across](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citation-rendering) a `--citation-abbreviations` option which sounds like it could be what I'm after, but I couldn't find further useful documentation for it.

Comment: The documentation would be here: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/blob/master/man/pandoc-citeproc.1.md

Comment: Do you mean that one short paragraph? I was hoping for something more extensive... To make things worse, the link to where the format is supposed to be described returns a 404. The Wayback Machine [comes to rescue](https://web.archive.org/web/20160731173816/http://citationstylist.org:80/2011/10/19/abbreviations-for-zotero-test-release/) once more, but reveals an unfinished blog post without an example instead of proper docs. Alas, I realised that this extension seems to go into a different direction than what I need.

Comment: Maybe ask on [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss)...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know of that mailing list. [Now this question became my first post there.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/3LVirBBVStg).